# How to Dispatch symfony events within entity manager transaction

Tags: symfony

I am looking for a smarter way to dispatch a symfony event within entity manager transactional, so that in case of rollback it won't complain.

Here's the sample of code:

```
$this->em->transactional(
            function () use ($xyz, $oldXyz) {
                if ($oldXyz !== null) {
                    $this->doRemove($oldXyz);
                }

                $this->em->persist($xyz);
            }
        );
```

Where:

```
    private function doRemove(XyzInterface $oldXyz): void
    {
        $this->em->remove($oldXyz);
        $this->em->flush();

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new XyzEvent($oldXyz), XyzEvents::onXyzDeleted);
        
    }
```

This thing will complain 'app.ERROR: Pending transaction on master connection' because this due to event dispatching cannot be rollback.

I can not move out event dispatch from doRemove, because it's used somewhere else plus it's job of doRemove to dispatch this event here, since actual removing happens here only.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why are you using transaction in this snippet? Is that real code? From what I see, you don't need at all the transaction.

Comment: @DonCallisto Thanks for your quick response. And answer of your question is yes, it's a real code with naming change. Let's say i want to persist $xyz, but since $oldXyz is still exist, i first need to remove this and persist new one. Now if this thing is not in transaction i might have inconsistency like, old one removed but new one couldn't persist or, old one couldn't removed and new one is trying to persist etc..

Answer (score 1):

Just return `$oldXyz` to the caller (by editing the closure as follows)

```
function () use ($xyz, $oldXyz) {
  if ($oldXyz !== null) {
    $this->doRemove($oldXyz);

    return $oldXyz;
  }

  $this->em->persist($xyz);

  return null;
}
```

Then check for returned value and dispatch

```
$oldXyz = $this->em->transactional(...);
if ($oldXyz instanceof <FQCNForOldXyz>) {
  $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new XyzEvent($oldXyz), XyzEvents::onXyzDeleted);
}
```

Didn't tried directly, but I'm pretty confident it works.